# Mail Service alternative for Swisscom Application Cloud (Public)

Tags: swisscomdev

For our swisscom app cloud applications (public app cloud), we need a swiss mail service (like mailgun, sendgrid,...) to send mails to our customers. Is there a service from Swisscom or another swiss provider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swisscom doesn't offer Mail aaS. Sorry. Please subscribe to our newsletter for announcement of new services.

We have some "manual" workaround, but it only works if you have access to a Swisscom internal Exchange mailbox (for example if you are a Swisscom partner).